# 2 instances of jquery in conflict

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery for a navigation bar as well as a home banner slider. Can anyone tell me what is conflicting here? Both plugins work on their own. But when I install the slider, the navigation is all out of whack.

```
<script type="text/javascript"        
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global/4.0/head-foot/head.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global/4.0/middle/base/nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alert.uconn.edu/alert/alert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>


<!--Home Banner BEGIN -->
<link href="fmslideshow_asset/fmslideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="fmslideshow_asset/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="fmslideshow_asset/fmslideshow.js"></script>


<script>
jQuery(function($){
 $('#jq_fmslideshow').fmslideshow({
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are referencing both jquery 1.3.2 & 1.6.2. You should remove one of them.

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of jQuery on the same page?

Comment: Why do you use two jQueries? Are you using an outdated plugin that can't handle 1.6.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a single latest jquery.min.js file. Try like below.

```
<script src="fmslideshow_asset/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global/4.0/head-foot/head.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global/4.0/middle/base/nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alert.uconn.edu/alert/alert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>


<!--Home Banner BEGIN -->
<link href="fmslideshow_asset/fmslideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="fmslideshow_asset/fmslideshow.js"></script>


<script>
jQuery(function(){
 $('#jq_fmslideshow').fmslideshow({
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be like:

```
$(function(){
 $('#jq_fmslideshow').fmslideshow({
 });
});
```

Hope it helps